# unsigned int decrement is ok but when taking it modulus it gives wrong result

Tags: c#

The if code gives correct result but the else portion gives output: `3,2,1,0` and I expecting `6,5,4,3,2,1,0` result.

```
uint  counter = 0;
private void getting_Next_Pic()
{
    if(next == true)// Here "**next**" is boolean variable
    {
        counter = ++counter % 7;   // Getting the next pic, Flow in Forward Direction
    }
    else
    {
        counter = counter-- % 7;   // Getting the previous pic, Flow in Reverse Direction
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug it and see what is the value of `counter` on each execution. I suspect that you didn't navigated to the next picture enought times, so counter was not increased as many times as you think.

Comment: I suspect you're wrapping past zero to uint.max; all bets are off at that point... it is *not* the case that it is guaranteed to modulo nicely when wrapping around an overflow

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `counter--` instead of `--counter`? Maybe you shouldn't use either `++` or `--` if you're just going to reassign `counter` anyway?

Comment: It's [modulus (with a 'u' at the end)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).  "Modules" are part of [Modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming).

Comment: I think there is problem in my **Visual Studio Compiler** because it gives right answer by compiling it on online compiler. Thanks

Comment: @Idle_Mind: it's actually not _"modulus"_ at all. The `%` operator in C# is the _remainder_ operator, and produces something similar to but subtly, and importantly, different from a modulus operation.

Comment: _"I think there is problem in my Visual Studio Compiler"_ -- nope. There's a problem with your code. If an online compiler produces the expected result, then that compiler is broken. More likely, you've just made a mistake in whatever test you performed using the online compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator is the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-). It produces the remainder of the division of the operands (the result is negative when the left-hand operand is negative).

The decrement operator when applied to a `uint` value of `0` results in the *positive* value `4,294,967,295`. The remainder of dividing that number by `7` is `3` (`613,566,756` times `7` is `4,294,967,292`, which is `3` less than `uint.MaxValue`, i.e. `4,294,967,295`).

In other words, the code's doing exactly what you told it to. You can't rely on the remainder operator to handle your scenario, not when the data type you're using is unsigned.

Note that this would work:

```cs
uint counter = 0;
private void getting_Next_Pic()
{
    if(next == true)// Here "**next**" is boolean variable
    {
        counter = (counter + 1) % 7;   // Getting the next pic, Flow in Forward Direction
    }
    else
    {
        counter = (counter + 6) % 7;   // Getting the previous pic, Flow in Reverse Direction
    }
}
```

Adding `6` is the same as subtracting `1` modulus `7`.

All that said, I prefer not using the remainder operator for this sort of thing. There is really no need for tricky code, or even trying to optimize performance (even assuming the remainder operator did that, which in most cases it does not). IMHO it's better to just do the actual range checking that you actually care about:

```cs
int counter = 0;
private void getting_Next_Pic()
{
    counter += next ? 1 : -1;

    if (counter < 0)
    {
        counter = 6;
    }
    else if (counter > 6)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Then when you read the code, it actually says exactly what it's doing. It's easy to verify it's correct, and won't confuse you or anyone else trying to figure it out again later.